# Geometric Series into Maclaurin Series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Expand 1/(1+x) into Maclaurin Series

I found f(0)=1, f'(0)=1, f''(0)=2!, f'''(0)=3! and so on
Therefore f^(k)(0)=k! so would the series centered at 0 be equal to x^k ?

Just want to check to see if I did it right.

Answer (score 2):

We know that
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,\quad \forall x:|x|<1$$

and it's the Maclaurin series so for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ replace $x$ by $-x$ and we find
$$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^nn!$$

Comment: can you show how you would go from the function and expand into (-1)^n(n!) ?

Comment: The Maclaurin series of a function $f$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$.

Comment: i'm really lost. i need someone to help me walk through this. i know the formula but can't translate that into this problem to solve it.

Comment: If we replace $x$ by $-x$ in the geometric series we find $\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n$ and it's the Maclaurin series so compare this series with its general form we find that $f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n n!$ isn't it?

Comment: yes i understand that but i want to find the answer without knowing the maclaurin series for 1/(1-x)...i want to be able to start from scratch and show my work instead of working from associations

Comment: There's a second method: first you should calculate the first derivatives of $f$ and find a  pattern then you prove the result by induction and finally take the value of this derivative at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Check your calculation of the derivatives for sign errors, but you almost have the right answer.  Is $1/(1+x)$ a decreasing function for $x > -1$?  If so, what should the sign of the first derivative be at $0$, for example?